# Error Message Construction

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have a programming project I'm working on for school. I have constructed the structure of the project. Essentially, I'm turning this logic gate into code so a user can input 1 or 0 and get the output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLOmd.jpg
When the program runs though, and a user inputs 2 (for example) or any other number than 0,1 I want an error message to pop up. I have tried the if: else: statement but I get invalid syntax error when I do this.

```
#Main instructions
A = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 1st input: ')

B = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 2nd input: ')

C = input ('Enter 0 or 1 for 3rd input: ')

print 'The logic diagram, LOGIC-1 evaluates for the input values, A, B and C to X'

print "input 1 =",A

print "input 2 =",B

print "input 3 =",C

print (A and not B) and (C or not B)
```

Comment: In the future, instead of saying "I get invalid syntax error when I do this", show the actual code, and the complete syntax error traceback. Even if _you_ can't understand exactly what it's telling you, someone here probably can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 1st input: ')
if A not in (0, 1): raise Exception ('Your error message')
```

Or if you want to ask for input until it is valid:

```
A = 42
while A not in (0, 1): 
    A = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 1st input: ')
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the exception function. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to help. `Exception` is not a function, but a class.